# Found this JavaScript on JSFiddle and cannot seem to get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copied all of the JSFiddle code and attempted to execute it in codepen. The html and css seems to work just fine. My goal is to create draggable divs and draw lines between them. It seems as though I am missing a library. On JSFiddle it says pure JS no-library but clearly they are using JQuery.  [Here is the link to the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmf4oewg/). Thanks for the help.

In addition, once I place the draggable div to the location that is suitable, I would like to store the position. This is secondary to my current problem, but if anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it. Thanks.

```
! function(a) {
  function f(a, b) {
    if (!(a.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
      a.preventDefault();
      var c = a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0],
        d = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      d.initMouseEvent(b, !0, !0, window, 1, c.screenX, c.screenY, c.clientX, c.clientY, !1, 
!1, !1, !1, 0, null), a.target.dispatchEvent(d)
    }
  }
  if (a.support.touch = "ontouchend" in document, a.support.touch) {
    var e, b = a.ui.mouse.prototype,
      c = b._mouseInit,
      d = b._mouseDestroy;
    b._touchStart = function(a) {
      var b = this;
      !e && b._mouseCapture(a.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]) && (e = !0, b._touchMoved = 
!1, f(a, "mouseover"), f(a, "mousemove"), f(a, "mousedown"))
    }, b._touchMove = function(a) {
      e && (this._touchMoved = !0, f(a, "mousemove"))
    }, b._touchEnd = function(a) {
      e && (f(a, "mouseup"), f(a, "mouseout"), this._touchMoved || f(a, "click"), e = !1)
    }, b._mouseInit = function() {
      var b = this;
      b.element.bind({
        touchstart: a.proxy(b, "_touchStart"),
        touchmove: a.proxy(b, "_touchMove"),
        touchend: a.proxy(b, "_touchEnd")
      }), c.call(b)
    }, b._mouseDestroy = function() {
      var b = this;
      b.element.unbind({
        touchstart: a.proxy(b, "_touchStart"),
        touchmove: a.proxy(b, "_touchMove"),
        touchend: a.proxy(b, "_touchEnd")
      }), d.call(b)
    }
  }
}(jQuery);



$('.anchor').on('click', function() {
  var width = parseInt($(this).parent().css('width'));
  if (width == 10) {
    $(this).parent().css('width', '20%');
    $('#canvas').css('width', '60%');
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css('width', '10px');
    $('#canvas').css('width', 'calc( 80% - 10px)');
  }
});

$('.ui-item').draggable({
   containment: "#canvas",
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var lines = $(this).data('lines');
    var con_item = $(this).data('connected-item');
    var con_lines = $(this).data('connected-lines');

    if (lines) {
      lines.forEach(function(line, id) {
        $(line).attr('x1', $(this).position().left).attr('y1', $(this).position().top + 1);
      }.bind(this));
    }

    if (con_lines) {
      con_lines.forEach(function(con_line, id) {
         $(con_line).attr('x2', $(this).position().left + 5)
          .attr('y2', $(this).position().top + (parseInt($(this).css('height')) / 2) + (id * 
5));
      }.bind(this));

    }

  }
});

$('.ui-item').droppable({
  accept: '.con_anchor',
   drop: function(event, ui) {
    var item = ui.draggable.closest('.ui-item');
    $(this).data('connected-item', item);
    ui.draggable.css({
      top: -2,
      left: -2,
    });
    item.data('lines').push(item.data('line'));

    if ($(this).data('connected-lines')) {
      $(this).data('connected-lines').push(item.data('line'));

      var y2_ = parseInt(item.data('line').attr('y2'));
      item.data('line').attr('y2', y2_ + $(this).data('connected-lines').length * 5);

    } else $(this).data('connected-lines', [item.data('line')]);

    item.data('line', null);
    console.log('dropped');
  }
 });


 $('.con_anchor').draggable({
  containment: "#canvas",
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var _end = $(event.target).parent().position();
    var end = $(event.target).position();
    if (_end && end)
      $(event.target).parent().data('line')
      .attr('x2', end.left + _end.left + 5).attr('y2', end.top + _end.top + 2);
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.helper.closest('.ui-item').data('line')) return;
    ui.helper.css({
      top: -2,
      left: -2,
    });
    ui.helper.closest('.ui-item').data('line').remove();
    ui.helper.closest('.ui-item').data('line', null);
    console.log('stopped');
  }
});


$('.con_anchor').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  var cur_ui_item = $(this).closest('.ui-item');
  var connector = $('#connector_canvas');
  var cur_con;

  if (!$(cur_ui_item).data('lines')) $(cur_ui_item).data('lines', []);

  if (!$(cur_ui_item).data('line')) {
    cur_con = $(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line'));
    cur_ui_item.data('line', cur_con);
  } else cur_con = cur_ui_item.data('line');

  connector.append(cur_con);
  var start = cur_ui_item.position();
  cur_con.attr('x1', start.left).attr('y1', start.top + 1);
  cur_con.attr('x2', start.left + 1).attr('y2', start.top + 1);
});
```

Comment: That JavaScript is a nightmare to read. Maybe start (for both your own benefit, and the benefit of anyone trying to help you solve this) with cleaning it up and renaming some variables to make it more legible.

Comment: "*On JSFiddle it says pure JS no-library*" - check the `resources` section on the left - uses jquery (1.12) and jquery-ui

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you so much! I am new to JSFiddle and I knew I was missing the libraries! You are the man!

Comment: @freedomn-m - Is there any chance you can point me in a direction where I can manipulate this JSFiddle so that I can save the locations and lines on reload?

Comment: No idea and the code is too unreadable to pick apart.  My recommendation is to delete this question and ask a new one without the "can't get it to work" parts - ie ask what you now need to ask (now that you've got the first part out of the way).  You could edit this question, but would likely get fewer "hits".